# mix-blend-mode multiply works different in FF and Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, filter

I'm tinkering with the mix-blend-mode properties to apply color filters onto images, but it seems like the way mix-blend-mode multiply works different ways in Chrome and FF.

```css
.filter {
  position: relative;
}
.filter::before,
.filter::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
}
.filter--rise {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(1.2) contrast(0.9) saturate(90%);
  filter: brightness(1.2) contrast(0.9) saturate(90%);
}
.filter--rise::before {
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(236, 205, 169, 0.2) 55%, #321E07 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(236, 205, 169, 0.2) 55%, #321E07 100%);
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.filter--rise::after {
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(246, 189, 57, 0.6), transparent 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(246, 189, 57, 0.6), transparent 100%);
  mix-blend-mode: overlay;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<figure class="filter filter--rise">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/KQ0U5BL.jpg" alt="">
  <figcaption>Rise</figcaption>
</figure>
```

And this is the result (left is chrome, right is FF - the intended result was in FF).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tMcF.png

Can someone explain to me why this happened? (and why only this mode because other modes e.g hard-light, overlay, etc. work the same)

Comment: I'm seeing the result on the right side for both Firefox and Chrome. What version of Chrome are you using? Keep in mind that `mix-blend-mode` is part of a specification that is only in Candidate Recommendation status. It was enabled by default in [Chrome starting with v41](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: I have the latest versions of both (Chrome 46 and FF 42)

Answer (score 0):

This is [an issue in Chrome 46 on Windows](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=543583). Looks like it has been fixed in 47.